# Print Unique Elements in an Array using Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have an int Array of M numbers, I want to spawn N threads that will read at least one element from it and print it.
The conditions are 
1. Each thread should print unique Element
2. Each Thread should print at least one element.
   I just need an idea of how it can be achieved .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this homework, where you have no choice but to do things this way? Otherwise, it's pretty close to the worst possible case for using threads. It's about equivalent to saying: "I want to sail around the world. But instead of a boat, I'm going to do it in a sieve."

Comment: Actually I wanted a Selection Algorithm using Threads.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: this is more of a comment (that's way too long to fit in the comment space) than a direct answer to the question.

The fundamental problem with what you're asking is that nearly everything you want done depends (heavily) on interaction between all the data, and (if you really insist on doing it with threads) between all the threads.

The first requirement is for each thread to select a unique item from a group. Selecting unique items implies that all the threads have at least some awareness of what data the other threads will select.

If you're willing to do virtually all the work in a single thread, you can make that easy. The obvious method would be to sort the data and remove all duplicates. Then having each thread select a unique element is trivial: give each thread an index of an element to select, and it's done.

Unfortunately, that also means the threads are doing essentially none of the work.

The next step is just about as bad (possibly even worse). Each thread needs to print out its data. At least assuming a normal stream-like output mechanism like `std::cout`, to keep the result from being a scrambled mess you need to use something like a mutex to assure that only one thread prints something at a time, then when it's finished some other thread and prints its output, and so on. In short, it *has* to be done entirely serially to keep the output meaningful at all.

To make a long story short, all the real work ends up being done by a single thread at the beginning to produce the sorted, unique data, and at the end to write out results serially. The task in between that can be executed in parallel is so trivial it's almost meaningless.

The ideal situation for threads is the opposite of this in essentially all respects. What you'd like is to be able to split the data up very quickly, then have lots of threads to almost all the real work without needing to synchronize with other threads at all.

Now, if you're willing to put some work into a dead-end task, it *is* possible to do at least some of that with the task you've outlined. For example, let's assume the data you care about are numbers. You could start with one thread that just partitions those numbers into ranges (e.g., by looking only at the most significant digits). Then you could have a thread for each range that sub-divides those numbers further still (e.g., based on the next digit). When you've divided the data into as many ranges as you want unique numbers, each thread just selects one number from its range and prints it out.

For small numbers, using threads for this task may still be a net loss, but if you have enough inputs and (especially) large enough inputs that you really gain something by looking at only a few digits instead of comparing complete numbers, this could be a win.